# problem on ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, django, numpy, scikit-learn, pycharm

i am working with django on pychrm, i have tested a project and everything is working, but when i tried to use another project and go back to the first project i have this error there

```
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\appweb pred21\predict\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\appweb pred21\predict\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ml_code.ml_process import server_predictor
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\appweb pred21\ml_code\ml_process\server_predictor.py", line 3, in <mod
ule>
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "sklearn\utils\murmurhash.pyx", line 26, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash
  File "__init__.pxd", line 1000, in numpy.import_array
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

so where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

you need `on_delete` keyword for defining `ForeignKey` relation, its mandatory in new versions of `Django`.

after changing dont forget to do `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: if you dont, then the error will persist. there is no problem with package. if you want downgrade your django version